# KOTLIN: Refactoring a big return when conditional clause coupled with another one

Tags: kotlin, refactoring, sealed-class

'Tis a design and technical code-wise question, so during some refactoring I was doing on a random project to bring it up to date, I encountered the following part, an infix function on a sealed class that was doing some sort of validation:

```
infix fun TaskState.allowsOperation(operation: TaskOperation): Boolean {
    return when (this) {
        TaskState.Scheduled -> {
            when (operation) {
                TaskOperation.Start -> true
                TaskOperation.Stop -> false
                TaskOperation.Pause -> false
                TaskOperation.Resume -> false
            }
        }
        TaskState.Running -> {
            when (operation) {
                TaskOperation.Start -> false
                TaskOperation.Stop -> true
                TaskOperation.Pause -> true
                TaskOperation.Resume -> false
            }
        }
        TaskState.Stopped -> {
            when (operation) {
                TaskOperation.Start -> false
                TaskOperation.Stop -> false
                TaskOperation.Pause -> false
                TaskOperation.Resume -> false
            }
        }
        TaskState.Suspended -> {
            when (operation) {
                TaskOperation.Start -> false
                TaskOperation.Stop -> true
                TaskOperation.Pause -> false
                TaskOperation.Resume -> true
            }
        }
        TaskState.Terminated -> {
            when (operation) {
                TaskOperation.Start -> true
                TaskOperation.Stop -> false
                TaskOperation.Pause -> false
                TaskOperation.Resume -> false
            }
        }
        TaskState.Created -> {
            when (operation) {
                TaskOperation.Start -> true
                TaskOperation.Stop -> false
                TaskOperation.Pause -> false
                TaskOperation.Resume -> false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, what's happening there was a sugar syntax addition that allowed code to be called like this in other parts:

`if (task.state allowsOperation operation) doSomething()`

However, I find that particular bunch of code to look ugly, and I could not come up with a reasonable another way of doing it, but at the same time to not produce too many changes.

The TaskState and TaskOperation are just some sealed classes:

```
sealed class TaskState {
    object Created : TaskState()
    object Scheduled : TaskState()
    object Running : TaskState()
    object Stopped : TaskState()
    object Terminated : TaskState()
}
```

```
sealed class TaskOperation {
    object Start : TaskOperation()
    object Stop : TaskOperation()
    object Pause : TaskOperation()
    object Resume : TaskOperation()
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to refactor this type of thingy?

Comment: Please add your code as text instead of images. It's a lot easier to read or copy it somewhere else that way. Also, if your code already works, and you just want to make it prettier, you should try asking this on Code Review Stack Exchange

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10134209) for many reasons why posting images of code is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've edited and put text, didn't think about it. :) Also, never actually even know about the Code Review Stack Exchange -> I'm going on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for these to be sealed classes, because every subclass is an `object`, and none of them have any distinct parameters. Just use enums, but you'll have to remove all the `is` keywords in places where `when` statements have been used on one of these.

You could simplify the amount of code by giving the `TaskState` class a parameter for allowable operations. This can replace everything you have above.

```
enum class TaskOperation {
    Start, Stop, Pause, Resume
}

enum class TaskState(private vararg val allowableOperations: TaskOperation) {
    Scheduled(TaskOperation.Start),
    Running(TaskOperation.Stop, TaskOperation.Pause),
    Stopped(),
    Suspended(TaskOperation.Stop, TaskOperation.Resume),
    Terminated(TaskOperation.Start);

    infix fun allowsOperation(operation: TaskOperation) = operation in allowableOperations
}
```

Also, this is opinion, but I think it's silly and bad for readability to use `infix` if the function doesn't join or compare two things.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 6 cases when the function can return `true` and 14 cases it could return `false`

In this case, we could handle only `true` branches like this:

```
fun TaskState.allowsOperation(operation: TaskOperation): Boolean {
    return when (this to operation) {
        TaskState.Scheduled to TaskOperation.Start -> true

        TaskState.Running to TaskOperation.Stop -> true
        TaskState.Running to TaskOperation.Pause -> true

        TaskState.Suspended to TaskOperation.Stop -> true
        TaskState.Suspended to TaskOperation.Resume -> true

        TaskState.Terminated to TaskOperation.Start -> true

        else -> false
    }
}
```